# Multiplot save png

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to save 2 charts on a png file. But it save only the last one. Here is my code.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 

png(filename="file.png")
barplot(plot1)           
plot(plot2)
dev.off()
```

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
png(filename="file.png")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
barplot(plot1)           
plot(plot2)
dev.off()
```

Swap your first two lines. This should work.